Is there a "database of cheat games"?
I want to train an AI to distinguish cheaters from normal players, as part of an AI-related course program. Is there any dataset of caught (engine) cheaters' cheat games?
An engine-cheat game is different to engine game. We assume engine-assisted player might not follow entirely engine's selection, and also allocate time more arbitrarily.
I hope this is the correct place to ask it. If not, I hope to get some suggestions where should I ask for it.

PGN file (better with Elo and clock time information) format is preferred.
If there include games that a cheater eventually lost, cheater name need to be marked out.
Data from Lichess or other open-source database is preferred, to make comparison to normal games.
I hope it can be free or inexpensive, maybe less than $20 per 100k games is affordable.

